# amazon turk, submit is not working

Tags: mechanicalturk

I've created an amazon Turk HIT. 
after submitting the HIT. we are always getting emails from people telling us the submit is not working...

honestly, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

form inside my **HTML:**

```
<form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
    <div class="inputs">
        <label class="input-green"><input name="EXISTS" type="radio" value="YES" id="ckeck-yes">YES</label>
        <label class="input-red">  <input name="EXISTS" type="radio" value="NO"  id="ckeck-no">NO</label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="IMG_ID" value="${Img_ind}">
    <input type="hidden" id="assignment_id" name="assignmentId" value=""/>

    <p class="text-center"><input type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></p>   
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var checkedYes = document.getElementById('ckeck-yes');
    var checkedNo = document.getElementById('ckeck-no');

    window.onload = function() {
        var submitButtons = document.getElementById('submitButton');

        // Get the Assignment ID, which will be added to your URL by Mechanical Turk.
        var assignment_id = location.search.match(/assignmentId=(\w+)/)[1];
        document.getElementById("assignment_id").value = assignment_id;

        // Assignment ID "ASSIGNMENT_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE" of indicates preview mode.  Warn worker.
        if( assignment_id == "ASSIGNMENT_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE" ) {
            submitButtons.disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("click_accept_warning").style.display = "block";
        }

        // Get the Submit URL, which will be added to your URL by Mechanical Turk. */
        var submit_to_url_base = (location.search.match(/turkSubmitTo=([^=&]+)/)||[])[1];
        if(submit_to_url_base) {
          document.getElementById("mturk_form").action = submit_to_url_base + "/mturk/externalSubmit";
        }       


        if(submitButtons) {
            submitButtons.setAttribute('onclick', 'return validateForm()'); 
        }
    };

    function validateForm() {
        if(checkedYes.checked == false && checkedNo.checked == false) {
            alert("Please select the most matching result!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean *its not working?* the button click doesn't work, it fails to post back? And are you using tools like Firebug to diagnose it?

Comment: I'd be inclined to hard-code the submit URL. This doesn't change ever (except between sandbox and live server).

Comment: thanks, @JeremyThompson i am doing this for someone, i am not in the US, so i can't even test it..... do you see something wrong in my code?

Comment: @Thomas my HIT automatically available also in the sandbox. ? how i can identify that

Comment: if find the problem, after accepting the hit the FORM url changes to https%3A%2F%2Fworkersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit...        where the %3A%2F%2F is coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was amazon turk replace my http:// WITH http%3A%2F%2F

so i created a new hit, inspect the new HIT javascript and copied 2 javascript function from amazon example.

```
function decode(strToDecode) {
  var encoded = strToDecode;
  return unescape(encoded.replace(/\+/g,  " "));
};

function turkGetSubmitToHost() {
      return decode(turkGetParam("turkSubmitTo", "https://www.mturk.com"));
};  

  var form = document.getElementById("mturk_form"); 
  if (form) {
     form.action = turkGetSubmitToHost() + "/mturk/externalSubmit"; 
  }
```

thank you